# Almost Two the Same Code but Only One Output

Tags: php, html, mysql, bash

I'm working on a PHP project and I'm getting some information from the Linux server with a bash script. There are a few services and I need to show if they're running or not first.

Here is the first script (It's working):

```
service=foo
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
   echo "Foo is not running"
else
   echo "Foo is running"
fi
exit 0
```

This is the HTML content for display that result for that script:

```
<div class="foo_status">
    <?php $foo_state = shell_exec("/var/www/cenk/services/foo_status.sh");
    echo "$foo_state";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="foo_run" value="Run"/>
    <input type="submit" class="foo_stop" value="Stop"/>                                        
    <input type="submit" class="foo_restart" value="Restart"/>
</div>
```

I'm using the same code and script for **mysql** but nothing shows up.

Bash Script:

```
 service=mysql
            if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
        then
        echo "Mysql is not running"
        else
            echo "Mysql is running"
        fi

        exit 0
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="mysql_status">
    <?php $mysql_state = shell_exec("/var/www/cenk/services/mysql_status.sh");
    echo "$mysql_state";
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="mysql_run" value="Çalıştır"/>
    <input type="submit" class="mysql_stop" value="Durdur"/>
    <input type="submit" class="mysql_restart" value="Yeniden Başlat"/>
   </div>
```

First one seems like: foo is running "Start" "Stop" "Restart"

Second one seems like:               "Start" "Stop" "Restart"

Comment: Permissions on the file ok?

Comment: Instead of `grep $service` try `grep -i $service`.  Chances are that the service name differs in case.

Comment: @devnull I've updated my code as you mentioned but still getting the same empty result.

Comment: @Rob You were right, I don't know how I did it but the working one's permissions are set to 777, the other one's permissions are set to 644. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, permissions on the file were incorrect.